# Allow mods to edit a section of the about page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, tour

The /about page is a great intro to the Stack Exchange model, but pretty useless as an introduction to the actual *site* you're on. This makes the page useless for all SE regulars, as there's usually just a blub like "This is a free, community driven Q&A for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community."

How about allowing Mods to edit the first paragraph or so of the /about page just like they can with the FAQ? This way the community could decide on a nice little intro for the About page to be edited in by mods, just like the FAQ. It could help reduce scope confusion as in questions like [It's not easy to know what each Stack Exchange site is for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136082/its-not-easy-to-know-what-each-stack-exchange-site-is-for)

Comment: What would you put there that you wouldn't put in the FAQ?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek not too much (but there's plenty I would put in the FAQ I wouldn't put there), but the FAQ serving as the "About" is sort of weird. The FAQ is supposed to be more in-depth, while the About should be a quick blurb to let you know the 10,000 foot view

Comment: The problem primarily stems from http://i.stack.imgur.com/yZdPg.png the About being next to the FAQ for new users. Maybe About needs to be moved elsewhere?

Comment: @jcolebrand why? I don't really see what that solves, unless you just mean emphasize the FAQ and hide /about because it's kinda useless. They both serve useful and different purposes, but About only helps as a quick into to the model of the network, not so much the site.

Comment: @jcolebrand IMHO, a new user trying to familiarize themselves with a site should look at both.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136082/its-not-easy-to-know-what-each-stack-exchange-site-is-for/136084#comment380176_136084

Comment: Agreed, you shouldn't have to hunt for what a specific site's based on. I've had this issue and often hunt on the meta for someone else who **also** had this issue. If nothing else, it can cut down on questions posted in the wrong SE.

Comment: Ditto, +1. Yeah, technically, "What is this site **about**?" _is_ a FAQ, but in practice, if you're a user on an unfamiliar site wondering about that, and see two adjacent links that say "faq" and "**about**", which one are you going to click?

Answer (score 13):

In the [new /about page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics), moderators *can* edit the first paragraph:

[image]

In addition, there are subsections titled “Ask about” and “Don't ask about” that moderators can edit.

[image: screenshot from scifi.stackexchange.com/about]

And moderators can choose the question used as the example throughout the page, [subject to stringent constraints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page).