# SE engine won't let me choose example question for about page. Naughty engine

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, tour

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What determines the questions available for selection in the about-page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page)

The SE engine won't let me choose the example question for Chemistry:

> [image]

I know my right. I'm a mod! I should be able to do that. Hey, I swear I'm a mod! They sent me the email and the list of secret handshakes and all! Let me in, please!

Comment: but... but... but... _There are currently no viable question candidates for the About page_.

Comment: Looking at the options provided for Biology I'd guess that you need a relatively short question with at least 2 relatively short answers (but it isn't necessary to have one marked as accepted - don't know if they just pretend for the page or what)

Comment: @Rory here I thought size didn't matter, and you're telling me we're too long :(

Comment: They won't let you in unless you remember the secret door-knock, obviously. The secret handshakes are so we can recognize each other on the next Mod Moon Meetup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pick *any* question for the about page, there are [certain restrictions](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/92077/aboutable-questions). For example the question and its answers should be relatively short, and can't have any fancy formatting.

Apparently there are currently no questions on Chemistry that satisfy those restrictions, if they were you would see a list:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I see the list on French L&U. Most Chemistry questions have HTML or MathJAX formatting, which may explain why none fits the bill…

Comment: @F'x: It's nothing to do with MathJax (I see some MathJax qs on the choosing page on Physics). It's got to do with the fact that short answers/questions are frowned upon, especially on science sites where the concept is paramount.