# Better about page example questions/answers/comments

Tags: discussion, tour

First of all, I really like the new about pages for SE sites. I think they do a much better job of explaining to new users how things work. There is one thing I don't like. Some of the example questions, answers, and comments featured on the about page don't seem to capture exactly what we want these posts to be. I would guess these are probably chosen automatically by the system, but I think we could pick some better examples.

For example, I saw the following question featued on the Code Golf about page:

[image: How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies]

Now I have no doubt that unicorns are as much a part of the culture at Code Golf as they are here on MSO, but I think it would be best to show a different question on the about page, since elsewhere on the about page it gives these guidelines for questions:

[image: Don't ask about... Anything that's not a programming puzzle or code golf]

*EDIT: Evidently, this post about unicorns and daisies is the default example for SE about pages if certain requirements aren't met. See @slhck's second comment on [my post at Meta.SU](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6430/171544).*

Also, on the Super User about page, I saw the following answer featured:

[image: I understand you can use the same mouse with different laptop with no ... port. When did the problem start? This is a weird one :P]

If you look at the [actual question's page](https://superuser.com/a/548957/171544), the answer shown as accepted on the about page is just another answer on the page. I don't frequent SU, but from the portion shown on the about page, that looks more like a comment than an answer. (If you look at the actual answer [actual answer](https://superuser.com/a/548957/171544), it has a few more the words that make it a possible answer rather than a comment, but these are hidden on the about page.)

Now I'm probably being nitpicky on this one, but later on the SU about page, I saw this comment featured (Notice the bad grammar):
[image: i don't remember . more than 6 months .]

I would really rather see the questions, answers, and comments on the about pages being the some of the best on the site. Either someone has a really bad sense of humor (that in this case is probably not beneficial to new users) or the system is automatically picking these examples.

**Instead of having the examples on the about page automatically picked by the system as they seem to be now, can these examples be hand-picked by the community, mods, or SE team?**

Comment: Wow, if those are indeed automatically selected, this is a pretty good case against that practice.

Comment: As of right now, I still see these both on the about pages: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/about and http://superuser.com/about

Comment: Totally agree, that is a really bad example. It's common knowledge that unicorns love corn syrup, that is obviously a troll answer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already implemented.

If there are eligible questions (short, with around 2 short answers, and relatively upvoted), the system will pick one automatically to begin with. That site's moderators can then change the question to any of the other eligible questions.

See for example, **[The Anime and Manga /about page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/about)**. It doesn't feature unicorns. The question there is **[a question actually asked on the site.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/361/was-dragon-ball-gt-made-by-fans)**

If there aren't any eligible questions (yet), the default unicorn question would be displayed. It may be possible that it needs improving, but that's a different matter.

Comment: This would explain why the SO about examples are from 2012, but others I've seen are more recent. The questions I saw on the about pages for the SU and Code Golf were also actually asked on the site, but I guess the system just happened to pick them instead of better ones.

Comment: @jdwire: Start a meta post on it on your own site. Tell moderators to pick a different one, if there's an eligible one, they can.

Comment: I hope the mods on these other sites make it a higher priority to pick a better question. Is there a way to suggest it to them?

Comment: Actually, I don't usually visit many other SE sites besides SO (which seems to have already dome this). Should I still post on the sites' metas or leave it for someone who visits the site more regularly?

Comment: @jdwire: What site are we talking about? Like I said, starting a meta post on the site itself (for instance, for [su] there's [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/)).

Comment: I just happened to see them on SU and Code Golf. I usually don't do much on those sites, but I'll go ahead and post on their metas.

Comment: Just posted at [SU](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6430/171544) and [Code Golf](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/616/7471).