# Some problems with "about" pages

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, tour

### The accepted answer of the question on EE.SE is outscored 150% by another answer, making it a bad example for how the site works.

The about page: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/about

The question (where the answer which pretends to have 3 upvotes below actually has 10): [How to remove solder mask?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81723/how-to-remove-solder-mask)

[image: about page]

### <s>The accepted answer of the question on Apple.SE is WRONG!</s>

[See my question on their meta for more info](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/the-accepted-answer-of-the-ask-different-example-question-is-wrong). The accepted (score 18) answer was true until apple released OS X 10.9 Mavericks a few months ago. The now-correct answer has a score of 2. Fixed-ish. Now the answer that shows as accepted on the about page is actually the one with the least upvotes.

### 13 sites still use "How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies", as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169946/better-about-page-example-questions-answers-comments).

Those sites are:

- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/about
- https://christianity.stackexchange.com/about
- https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/about
- https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/about
- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/about
- https://politics.stackexchange.com/about
- https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/about
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/about
- https://pets.stackexchange.com/about
- https://italian.stackexchange.com/about
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/about
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/about
- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/about

Should I ask a question on each of those 12 meta sites? can something be done centrally about it?

Comment: Moderators can select which one to example

Comment: @random I think you forgot a

Comment: Thanks for pointing out our question that had outdated answers voted more highly than the current correct answer. Not only have I swapped it out for a fresh question - but bounties have been placed to let the community improve both the incoming and outgoing question. Cheers!

Comment: just out of curiosity, which site was the unicorn question asked on?

Comment: Server Fault meta, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something you'll have to bring up with the individual sites.

Those that showcase the unicorn are because the moderators haven't picked a question from [the available list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page).

Moderators, when viewing the About page, will see a link to "edit question". [By editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136086/allow-mods-to-edit-a-section-of-the-about-page), they are picking and by picking they are showing it off.

Those that are showing less than sunshine for the example, probably could pick a better question to highlight.