# A weird sample question on the tour page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange.com, tour

On [stackexchange.com/tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) the sample question is very unscholarly and hypothetical. I don't think it is on-topic on any community here.

Should we have something like that on the tour page?

[image]

The question was [changed](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=How+to+prevent+unicorns+from+eating+daisies) on other domains.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169946/312043) ?

Comment: @JasonC cat gifs ...

Comment: Huh, a Lifehacks-specific question on the main site tour. Not fair.

Comment: It is [an official meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479) (and the very first one posted).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR - can't see any bug or problem here.

stackexchange.com is the portal of the whole network. This is **not** a Q&A site on its own.

So, being "on topic" is not relevant there.

As can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/152859), unicorns are a very popular meme in Meta Stack Exchange, hence in SE in general. So it just fits for choosing as a sample question which should not target any specific site.

Each site can choose its own sample questions (i.e. the site moderators can), so really can't see any problem with this mechanism.

Comment: (Popular in MSE ⇒ popular in SE in general) is a fallacy. (Popular in MSE ⇒ appropriate on a public-facing tour page) is also a fallacy. There's other factors at play but very little in this answer actually applies.

Comment: @E.P. well, MSE is the "front" of SE, in a way. Hard to explain, but think this is valid claim.

Comment: That's... kinda putting the cart before the horse in a way - MSE is the back end of SE, not the front, always has been, always should be. OP pointed out it's unscholarly, which it is, but this answer goes off in all sorts of tangents. Not that it matters, though, given the accept, beyond the observation that just because the MSE bubble-chamber has decided something is fun, it doesn't follow that all of SE agrees.

Comment: @E.P. well this goes beyond comments, guess we better discuss this in chat if you want. You know where to find me, or new room is always an option too. :)

Comment: Note: this same sample is the one used if a site hasn't yet chosen its actual on-the-site question yet (or doesn't have any that qualify). So it's not just SE. You may want to mention that specifically and explain why that doesn't change your point.

Comment: @Nathan yeah, you mean it's the default sample question, I'll try to see how I can mention this in the answer. Thanks!