# Moderators should be notified if the tour reverts to the unicorn question

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, unicorns, tour

The tour is not a page I visit regularly, so I wouldn’t notice if the example question there later became ineligible for selection and the system reverted to the generic "unicorn" example (as seen on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/tour)), which isn’t as helpful as a real question from the site as an example. Can moderators be notified when the example question reverts if they aren’t already?

I expect that this would only happen rarely but it’s important for someone to know so that it can be fixed.  (Moderators are the only ones who can change the example question or they can instead raise the issue on meta so everyone can decide.)

Further reading:

- [What determines the questions available for selection in the tour page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/323179)
- [Selecting an example for the Tour page's example question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13079/82909) (Sci-fi Meta)

Screenshot of the "unicorn" example:

[image: Unicorn example in the tour page]

Comment: This is particularly important for sites like SFF and Worldbuilding, as the unicorn question looks vaguely on-topic for those sites, and new users might mistake it for an example of a genuinely good question to ask on those sites (it isn't).

Answer (score 5):

While there would be benefits to having a feature specifically for this purpose, there is one feature that mods can use as a workaround: **The "follow" button**. Use it on the question and its answers. This will alert you to most changes that would make the question ineligible, such as being closed or substantially edited. You can't get an alert if users decide to downvote it a lot or the authors delete themselves, but that should hopefully be sufficiently rare as to not be an issue.

Comment: Users deleting their accounts can be common if a major scandal occurs on the network, such as the Monica affair of late 2019 or the AI strike earlier this year.