# If a post featured on a tour is edited, will the tour page display the revised version?

Tags: support, edits, moderator-tools, tour

I recently edited a question to format it more nicely, and edited its top two answers to make them more standard by our modern community consensuses and practices.

Then, I edited the tour page question, and the preview when asking me to confirm my choice showed the new info.

However, on the tour page itself, it shows an earlier revision of the question, which has a large amount of important detail chopped off, and the earlier revisions of the answers, which go by outdated practices.

Will this eventually update on its own? If the question or its answers are edited again after selecting for the tour page, will the tour page update? If neither of these happens, how long after editing the posts themselves do I need to wait before I select the tour page question?

Comment: This is for [CGCC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) by the way, and the relevant question is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence)

Comment: If the question that's currently selected for the tour later becomes [ineligible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-tour-page/337376) for selection, the system will revert the tour back to the generic "unicorn" question.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'm sorry, but that's just plain wrong. The previous question we had on the CGCC Tour ([this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11020/triangle-area-side-side-side)) was closed a month ago and stayed on the Tour until hyper-neutrino changed it [yesterday](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57763356#57763356). Additionally, by the criteria listed in your answer, it was never eligible in the first place, yet it's been in our Tour for years

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Don't know why it didn't change. Can tell you at least [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351469/377214) [documented](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3666/11936) cases of that happening.

Comment: It happened on English SE. A user [edited his answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/33861/191178) and I just now noticed that it had the unicorn question instead. Fortunately, the switch from that to a different question is immediate.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, editing a tour-question does normally update its appearance in the tour.

I don't have a screenshot of the original tour, but the featured question on [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/tour) is [this](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/31829/how-do-i-shout-into-my-mic-without-distortion), which was originally pretty chatty before I [edited](https://sound.stackexchange.com/posts/31829/revisions) it to make it slightly more serious. It took a few hours after approval for it to update, but the new version eventually displayed up.

Comment: When in doubt, [blame caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).